# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192 in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, indexoutofboundsexception, http-content-length

I am developing a web application. I am running this app on JBoss. In one page there are rows around 500. If I select lessthan 100 and there is button Edit if I click this its going to next page. If I select more than 300 rows it not going to the other page and showing the below error.

[image]

I am calling a jsp page from java calss. For that I am using response.sendRedirect() method. The following is the code

[image]

The below is the getResponse() code

[image]

I tried adding the content length in this java class as below but nothing is working. 
[image]

I am getting the below error on the server console. I searched a lot and tried in may ways. Nothing is working. Please help me in resolving this.

```
 [exec] 15:29:19,293 ERROR [CoyoteAdapter] An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
 [exec] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:698)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:605)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendHeader(InternalOutputBuffer.java:478)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1564)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:921)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:186)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:386)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:333)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:299)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:493)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 [exec] 15:32:32,892 ERROR [Http11Processor] Error finishing response
 [exec] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 [exec]     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:667)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendStatus(InternalOutputBuffer.java:403)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1553)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:921)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:184)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:363)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 [exec] 15:32:45,728 ERROR [CoyoteAdapter] An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
 [exec] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:698)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:605)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendHeader(InternalOutputBuffer.java:478)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1564)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:921)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:186)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:386)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:333)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:299)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:493)
 [exec]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 [exec] 15:32:45,729 ERROR [Http11Processor] Error finishing response
 [exec] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 [exec]     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:667)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendStatus(InternalOutputBuffer.java:403)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1553)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:921)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:184)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:363)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
 [exec]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
 [exec]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Include your code as text and not as a screenshot please.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your quick reply. I will do that next time on wards.

Comment: It looks like a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-982). What version are you using? Can you upgrade?

Comment: we are not able upgrade @assylias

Comment: we are using JBoss 5.1.0

Comment: The maximum size of the request and response HTTP header if not specified is set to 8192 (8 KB).
If exceeded, parsing will fail using an ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions.
You can increase the limit by setting the following parameter "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.MAX_HEADER_SIZE"